# CPQ Pricing Rule with custom PoT for each bundle depending on Configuration Attribute

Tags: cpq, cpq-plugins, pricerule, cpq-api, product-rule

I have many product bundles with same structure. Here i give example for four

**Product Bundle A**

- Product Bundle A1
- Product Bundle A2
- Product Bundle A3

**Product Bundle B**

- Product Bundle B1
- Product Bundle B2
- Product Bundle B3

**Product Bundle A Addon**

- Product Bundle A Addon A1
- Product Bundle A Addon A2
- Product Bundle A Addon A3

**Product Bundle B Addon**

- Product Bundle B Addon B1
- Product Bundle B Addon B2
- Product Bundle B Addon B3

I have one configuration attribute for each bundle which has values A,B & C
I am calculating the price for Products with A1 Category from custom Pricing table. For instance lets say custom table has returned 1000. then for Product A1 if user has selected 'C' in the configuration attribute then we need to apply 10% discount of the price of Product A1. Same goes for other products respectively. After applying discount price will be 900

I have been struggling to find a solution for this, and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!